# Is Xinerama causing issues with my code?

Tags: linux, x11, nvidia, drivers, xorg

After trying to get a basic "Hello World"-like XServer application up and running, I've found that, no matter what I try, I keep running into the same error, which is:

```
X Error of Failed request: BadMAtch( invalid parameter attributes )
Major opcode of failed request: 78 ( X_CreateColormap )
```

At first, I thought it was my drivers, so I updated them to 290.10 (nVidia).

My (relevant) setup consists of the following:

```
nVidia GTX 550 Ti
Sabayon Linux
Kernel 3.2
```

But, after some surfing, it seems like it could be either the fact that I have dual monitors (one connected to an hdmi-mini port, the other vga/dvi), or the fact that I have Xinerama enabled, or both.

I tried to compensate for both monitors by creating two `GLXContext` objects in my code, which, as expected, didn't do anything (be nice: I just started learning this API). I did this because it seemed like a GLXContext had something to do with monitor input/output.

After that didn't work, I tried `glXGetConfig`, and that didn't work either. So, I started looking around more and found a post on a forum (written a couple years ago) about someone having issues with disabling Xinerama, and that that was causing the issue. The weird thing was that this was posted back in 2009, so one would think that nVidia had fixed this by now.

I'm at a loss as to what to do, and I believe that I'm kind of screwed some how unless I can fix this.

Anyone can view my code [here](http://pastebin.com/MRyMxn4E) (pastebin), along with my post on SuperUser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/394165/disable-xinerama-effectively-in-sabayon).

I could really use some help on this one.

**tl;dr**

```
setWindowAtt.colormap = colorMap;
setWindowAtt.event_mask = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask;

win = XCreateWindow( dp, root, 0, 0, 600, 600, 0, visualInfo->depth, InputOutput,   visualInfo->visual, CWColormap | CWEventMask, &setWindowAtt );

XMapWindow( dp, win );

XStoreName( dp, win, VI_UN_DEF_WIN_NAME );

glxContext = glXCreateContext( dp, visualInfo, NULL, GL_TRUE ); //error

glXMakeCurrent( dp, win, glxContext );
```

Comment: Please provide [Short, Self Contained, Compilable, Example](http://sscce.org/). It will be much easier to analyse.

Answer (score 2):

The clue is right in front of you:

`Major opcode of failed request: 78 ( X_CreateColormap )`

That means `XCreateColormap` failed. If it wanted to tell you a GLX command had failed, it would have said something about GLX instead.

After reading the rest of your code: the visual you're getting from `glXChooseVisual` is probably a TrueColor-class visual, and - as the manual for `XCreateColormap` says - TrueColor visuals must be allocated with AllocNone, and will throw BadMatch if you don't.